# Wave:SelectionChanged event is not firing

Tags: einstein-analytics

I tried a lot but I don't know what I am missing to capture wave:SelectionChanged event.

Used same code as available on : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_sdk.meta/bi_dev_guide_sdk/bi_sdk_web_example2.htm

Steps Performed:

1. Added measure column in Table.
2. Added record Id column too in dashboard.
3. Have put both dashboard and Lightning component on lightning app page(one below the other).
4. on selecting the measure column no event is fired, tried putting console logs but the handle change did not trigged.

Please help me or suggest something on this.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000ITGb) wave:selectionChanged is not allowed to be fired from table with any column type.

Kindly review [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lOdeQAE) and vote for this feature.

Thanks